# Audio.js HTML5 volume control

Tags: jquery, html, audio

I'm using the [audio.js](http://kolber.github.com/audiojs/docs/) library for a project I'm working on and I'm having a hard time implementing a volume controller. I've tried contacting the developer who built the library, but haven't been able to reach him. I've built a volume slider using jQuery UI and I'm now trying to parse the value of the slider to all players in my instance using the [.setVolume](http://kolber.github.com/audiojs/docs/#section-62) function. I can't make it work though. Here's my code:

```
audiojs.events.ready(function() {

    var audio = audiojs.createAll(),
        slider = $('#slider');

    tooltip.hide();

    slider.slider({
        range: 'min',
        min: 1,
        value: 35,

        start: function(event,ui) {
            // Start
        },

        slide: function(event, ui) {

            var value = slider.slider('value');

            // Slide

        },

        stop: function(event,ui) {
            // Stop
        },

        change: function(event,ui) {
            audio.setVolume(ui.value / 100);
        },

    });

});
```

Comment: What is not working? are you getting any js error? Can you post the error?

Answer (score 1):

Without using `audio.js` library you can simply do it by using `volume` attribute of the audio element of HTML5.

For that, you can go with the below lines.

```
var myAudio = document.getElementById('myAudio');
myAudio.volume = 0.32;
```

Where Volume 1.0 is highest and 0.0 is the lowest volume.

Answer (score 0):

`audiojs.createAll()` creates an array, thus the variable `audio` is an array. If you are using one audio js player, then declare: `var audio = audio[0];` this should work. If you are using multiple, then you are going to need to either do a `for` loop or call the audio js player with the index number, such as `audio[0].setVolume(ui.value / 100);`.